# Teclado Cordova esconde inputs

Tags: apache-cordova, mobile, teclado

Estou desenvolvendo um `aplicativo hibrido` que utilizo o Cordova mais o HTML5 + jQuery e estou tendo um problema. Quando clico no campo do texto para digitar algo o evento automático do teclado é acionado e o teclado se posiciona em cima dos meus inputs.

O ideal seria ao clica em algum `input` apareça uma `div` do tamanho do teclado para que possibilite o deslise para visualizar o que está digitando.

Como devo resolver isto? Existe alguma função que faça isto automaticamente, ou eu deveria programar algo? Se sim, como fazer tal feito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renan, existe sim uma solução para isso e não é com a div como você sugeriu. É simplesmente uma configuração no config.xml. 
Veja:

`<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />`

Comment: So um minuto para testar.

Comment: Funcionou, porem tem outro problema que talvez saiba resolver. Você sabe o porque o aplicativo antes de inicializar fica com tela branca ?

Comment: Opa, sei sim. Isso é um recurso chamado "Splash Screen", provavelmente você não setou nenhuma imagem para ser a splash screen do seu app. É como se fosse uma imagem de loading, para que o usuário veja alguma coisa enquanto o app estrá sendo inicializado.
Você seta ela no mesmo arquivo que fez a configuração acima, no config.xml. É algo bem simples, você terá tudo o que precisa saber nesse link http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/config_ref/images.html
Se ainda tiver dúvida, volta ae.

Comment: O que não estou conseguindo é desabilitar esse splash, quero que entre direto em minha programação porem ja tentei de tudo e nada. Como tirar esta tela ? @wennderSantos

Comment: Não é possível @RenanRodrigues

Comment: Uai, então é obrigado ter esta tela feia toda vez que entra ? Eu vejo alguns aplicativos que não tem isso... Eu ja tentei definir outra splash porem a tela branca insiste em aparecer. E ao @wennderSantos

Comment: toda vez irá iniciar com a tela branca ? não como nem esconde-la, ou fazer algo com ela ?